# Why a red horizontal line in code tips when I use addTarget to add events, it is

Tags: objective-c, swift, addtarget

I have a UITextField and I try to use the addTarget to add a value change event, I pronounced a textFieldDidChange selector like below:

```
@objc private func textFieldDidChange(textFiled: UITextField) {

}
```

but when I  tried to input some prefix code of the selector, I found the code tips with a red horizontal line in the textFieldDidChange. I have no idea if there is any changes of using the addTarget, is it deprecated?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ESnH.png)

Comment: Go ahead and enter `textFieldDidChange` manually  and try to compile. What happens?

Comment: Running normally and no any errors or warnings.

Comment: Excellent! So don’t worry. Probably the issue with code completion is temporary. Quit Xcode and clean out DerivedData, and carry on.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but it doesn't work even though start Pc, quit Xcode and clean out the DeriveData. Also I still don't know the reason for this, maybe just a bug of Xcode. ^_^

Comment: Well try naming your method some thing else, like `textFieldHasChanged`. The name you are using is taken.

Comment: Actually I tried several other method names, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your goal, then instead of adding target add a delegate

```
self.textField.delegate = self // as UITextField is a UITextInput
```

and add conform controllers to `UITextInputDelegate`, where

```
   func textDidChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
       /// text field value changes will be reported here
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually my question is not to get the feature running because there is no any error and warnings. What I want to know is why the red line shows me the selector was deprecated. Another scenario is with a button, and also use the addTarget to add an action for it, then a red line above the selector in code hinting information.

Comment: @JonathanChen, I think it is because the signatures are not fit, action argument should be unnamed, try `@objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ textFiled: UITextField)`

Comment: I tried @objc private func textFieldDidChange(_ textFiled: UITextField), but the issue still there.

Comment: Finaly I got the anwser but I don‘t know why. Use self.textFieldDidChange to call the function.